# Error al hacer Publish mi proyecto (An error occurred while processing your request)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Estoy queriendo hacer `Publish` a mi proyecto web hospedado en un servidor, pero cuando abro la pagina web me tira el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo pruebo con `Debug`, osea localmente, funciona perfectamente, compila y hace todo lo que tiene que hacer correctamente. El proyecto está alojado en un servidor de testing, y está cfuncionando correctamente. Lo que más me llama la atención es que de 3 opciones que tiene la pagina web, solo 1 funciona:

Numero de pedido funciona bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero las otras dos opciones (Número de Remito y Número de Entrega) me tirar el error previamente mencionado.

No sé si es algo del código, no creo porque el problema es cuando realizo el `Publish`, y en `Debug` funciona bien. ¿Alguna idea de lo que puede llegar a ser?

Aclaración: No es la primera vez que hago un proyecto  lo publico, con los anteriores proyectos nunca tuve este problema.
Este es mi `launchSettings.json`, el cual buscando decia que era un problema de `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` y qe tenia que dejarlo como `"Development"`, pero en el archivo ya viene asi por defecto.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1111",
      "sslPort": 11111
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "WebLogistica": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:2222;http://localhost:3333",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Menciona a LeerOpcion (funcion en mi controlador):

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LeerOpcion(string seleccion, string identi)
        {
            try
            {
                identi = CleanString(identi);

                if (identi == null || identi == "")
                {
                    return View("Index");
                }

                switch (seleccion)
                {
                    case "pedido":
                        return View("Pedido", VerPedido(identi));
                    case "remito":
                        return View("Pedido", VerRemito(identi));
                    case "entrega":
                        return View("Pedido", VerEntrega(identi));
                }

                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

Éste es el código con la opción que funciona, el cual recibe el numero de pedido ingresado por usuario, busca la imagen en la carpeta por numero de pedido y la retorna. La imagen tiene esta ruta [carpetaVirtual]\carpetaProyecto\wwwroot\Imagenes\[numeroPedido]-[numeroRemito]-[numeroEntrega], por eso luego hago un `Split()` para poder separar el pedido del remito y entrega:

```
 private static List<PedidoViewModel> VerPedido(string identi)
        {
            string[] imagenes, rutaSplit, imagenRecuperada, rutaImagen, carpetaDia, carpetaMes, carpetaAnio;
            PedidoViewModel pedido;
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;

            try
            {
                listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();

                // \imagenes\..
                carpetaAnio = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imagenes\");

                foreach(var carAnio in carpetaAnio)
                {
                    carpetaMes = Directory.GetDirectories(carAnio);
                    foreach (var carMes in carpetaMes)
                    {
                        carpetaDia = Directory.GetDirectories(carMes);
                        foreach (var carDia in carpetaDia)
                        {
                            imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(carDia);
                            foreach (var img in imagenes)
                            {
                                rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
                                rutaImagen = img.Split("wwwroot");
                                imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[5].Split("_");

                                if (identi == imagenRecuperada[0])
                                {
                                    pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                                    pedido.setNumeroPedido(identi);
                                    pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                                    pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                                    pedido.setimagenes(rutaImagen[1]);
                                    pedido.setMonto("$11111");
                                    listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return listaPedidos;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Y éste es el código que me tira error, es el mismo solamente que en vez de buscar el numero de pedido busco el numero de pedido:

```
 private static List<PedidoViewModel> VerRemito(string identi)
        {
            string[] imagenes, rutaSplit, imagenRecuperada, rutaImagen, carpetaDia, carpetaMes, carpetaAnio;
            PedidoViewModel pedido;
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;

            try
            {
                listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();

                // \imagenes\..
                carpetaAnio = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imagenes\");

                foreach (var carAnio in carpetaAnio)
                {
                    carpetaMes = Directory.GetDirectories(carAnio);
                    foreach (var carMes in carpetaMes)
                    {
                        carpetaDia = Directory.GetDirectories(carMes);
                        foreach (var carDia in carpetaDia)
                        {
                            imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(carDia);
                            foreach (var img in imagenes)
                            {
                                rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
                                rutaImagen = img.Split("wwwroot");
                                imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[5].Split("_");
                                imagenRecuperada[2] = CleanString(imagenRecuperada[2]);

                                if (identi == imagenRecuperada[2])
                                {
                                    pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                                    pedido.setNumeroPedido(imagenRecuperada[0]);
                                    pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                                    pedido.setNumeroRemito(identi);
                                    pedido.setimagenes(rutaImagen[1]);
                                    pedido.setMonto("$11111");
                                    listaPedidos.Add(pedido);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return listaPedidos;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**Actualizacion:**

Agregue la siguiente linea en `.pubxml`: `<EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>`

Y ahora la vista es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION:**

Terminé creando una nueva instancia en el servidor y volví a publicar el proyecto y RARAMENTE funcionó la pagina web perfectamente.

Ahora hace unos dias actualice el Visual Studio y cuando publiqué denuevo la aplicación me volvió a tirar el mismo problema.

Es posible que las actualizaciones del Visual Studio "rompan" las aplicaciones que estás desarrollando?

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer `Publish` en `Release`?

Comment: Sip, lo eh intentado y  tampoco funciona

Comment: que quiere decir, cuando lo pruebo en debug? cuando lo probas local? entonces te falta algo en el servidor que hace que esas pantallas fallen. o generas un log, o activas el development mode en produccion, o tenes un servidor intermedio donde probarlo...

Comment: claro, debug es cuando lo pruebo Localmente. Tengo un servidor de prueba, en el que estoy autorizado.

Comment: no hay un error al hacer publish.. hay un error cuando cambias de ambiente, en este caso, tenes un error en produccion.. hay algo que tenes en tu servidor local, que no tenes en tu servidor de produccion (un archivo, la conexion a la base de datos).. hay que verificar todo eso...

Comment: En ese caso voy a hablarlo con la gente correspondiente para ver si hay un problema en el servidor , nunca tuve este problema, pero bueno creo que hay una primera vez para todo..

Comment: El tema es que me resulta raro porque como dije en el post, de 3 opciones solamente me deja hacer 1, y las conexiones y los datos a usar no cambian en casi nada. La conexion al servidor es la misma en las 3 opciones.